# Package is not executing from C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a package that runs fine from within BIDS (or whatever MS is calling VS for SSIS now) and from the execute package utility too.

I tried running it from C# using the following code but nothing happens. The .Execute returns success and the ExecutionStatus is Completed. The .Execute takes a few seconds when it should take a minute or two and it doesn't do what it's supposed to do (load source files, move them somewhere else, etc.)

```
var pkgLocation = @"C:\ImportMetricsPackage.dtsx";
var app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
var pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
var pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your code for starting an SSIS package is correct. The fact that it's not behaving as expected leaves me to believe that it's missing something when being started from code, a configuration perhaps and that it's running on default, possibly incorrect values. If you don't have logging turned on, try using a SQL Server target with the following events OnInformation, OnWarning, OnPreExecute, OnPostExecute, OnError and OnTaskFailed. Info & warning will identify configuration issues. Pre/Post will give task timings (what ran short). Error and fail just good practice. Rerun and examine output.

Comment: The OnTaskFailed is firing on the first SQL task. How can I get more information on why it fails? I tried a whole bunch of stuff to no avail (taskHost.Description/Name/ExecutionResult/ExecutionValue/InnerObject)

Comment: If you have the OnTaskFailed logging to a file or SQL table, you should be able to look at the message column. Otherwise, I'd think the code @alex Filipovic linked should work. If I were to hazard a guess, you're running into an authentication issue. This isn't being run from a web page or something like that, is it?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to capture the package events?

```
MyEventListener eventListener = new MyEventListener();

var pkgLocation = @"C:\ImportMetricsPackage.dtsx";
var app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, eventListener);
pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, null, eventListener, null, null);
```

The event listener class:

```
class MyEventListener : DefaultEvents
{
    public override bool OnError(DtsObject source, int errorCode, string subComponent, 
    string description, string helpFile, int helpContext, string idofInterfaceWithError)
    {
        // Add application-specific diagnostics here.
        Console.WriteLine("Error in {0}/{1} : {2}", source, subComponent, description);
        return false;
    }
}
```

For more details, see [Loading and Running a Local Package Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx).

Comment: Yup, no errors. I also tried OnPostExecute and it fires a few times before the package finishes executing (whatever it's doing).